# confusion of char* str="ab", str and &str

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers

I am learning pointer and this is my code. I defined a pointer to char (string actually) `*str` and a pointer to int `*a`, they are defined in the same way. I thought both `str` and `a` should be an address, but when I tried to output `str` and `&str`, `a` and `&a`, I found str is not an address, it is the string. What is the difference between char `*str` and int `*a` in terms of the type of `str` and `a`? Thank you.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        char *str = "FA";
        cout << "str: " << str << endl;
        cout << "&str: " << &str << endl;

        int b = 5;
        int *a = &b;
        cout << "a: " << a << endl;
        cout << "&a: " << &a << endl;
}
```

this is output:

```
str: FA
&str: 0x7fff5a627280
a: 0x7fff5a62727c
&a: 0x7fff5a627288
```

Comment: Prefer to use `const char *` for string literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<<` operator for streams has an overload for `char *` that outputs a C-style string. This is usually what you want, but if it's not what you want, you can use `reinterpret_cast<void*>` or `addressof`.

Comment: A more expressive solution is `cout << addressof(str)`

Comment: `addressof(str)` is a verbose alternative for the second output line, which is not problematic. Calling it "more expressive" is inane.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this comes down to C semantics. A string is **not** a type defined in C. `char` is the type of a **single** character. In order to handle strings in C, by convention a pointer to `char` means a string that starts at the position this pointer points to and ends at the first `0` byte.

To make that clear:

```
char *str = "ABC";
```

"translates" to something like

```
const char <nosymbol>[4] = {'A', 'B', 'C', '\0'};
char *str = &(<nosymbol>[0]);
```

C++ knows about this special meaning of a `char *` and so, the `<<` operator will, following the *principle of least surprise* for C programmers, take `char *` as a string.